# How to specify the vertice order and the edge order when obtaining the incidence matrix of a digraph in sage?

Tags: sage

We can obtain the incidence matrix of a digraph using the method [`incidence_matrix(oriented=None, sparse=True, vertices=None)` in SageMath](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.incidence_matrix).

> Each row is a vertex, and each column is an edge. The vertices are ordered as obtained by the method `vertices()`, except when parameter `vertices` is given, and the edges as obtained by the method `edge_iterator()`.

My question is how to specify the vertice order *and* the edge order?

---

For example, `g` is a weighted digraph with 10 edges:

```
edges = [('s', 'x', 3), ('s', 'y', 5),
         ('x', 'y', 2), ('x', 'z', 6),
         ('y', 'x', 1), ('y', 'z', 4), ('y', 't', 6),
         ('z', 't', 2),
         ('t', 's', 3), ('t', 'z', 7)]

g = DiGraph(edges)
```

I want to arrange the incidence matrix such that the vertices (from top to down) are ordered as `s, x, y, z, t` and the edges are ordered (from left to right) as those in `edges` (i.e., listing the edges in the alphabetic order `s, x, y, z, t`).

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the code (which you can obtain by doing `g.edge_iterator??`) for `edge_iterator()` suggests

> The iterator returned is over the edges incident with any vertex
> given in the parameter "vertices".

```
if oriented:
    for e, (i, j) in enumerate(self.edge_iterator(labels=False)):
        if i != j:
            m[verts[i],e] = -1
            m[verts[j],e] = +1
else:
    for e, (i, j) in enumerate(self.edge_iterator(labels=False)):
        m[verts[i],e] += 1
        m[verts[j],e] += 1
```

tells me that probably one would have to hack the code for this a bit to change the order.

This seems like a reasonable request to have this customizable, so I've opened [Sage issue 27513](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/27513) for this.

Comment: Is there a version of this customizable incidence matrix for incidence structures?
I am having a similar trouble with the incidence matrix of an incidence structure.
The relevant functions are 
IncidenceStructure() and .incidence_matrix()

Comment: Probably you'd have to look at the code there as well, and perhaps you have already done so based on [this comment](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/27513#issuecomment-1676772329), which is great.

Comment: I ended up defining the incidence matrix myself, which was a one-liner. However, it would be nice to have it as a feature in the function .incidence_matrix()